# How to savechanges if approved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Right so I have two tables in my database called Employees and HolidayRequestForm.

The Employee table tracks employee information such as holiday hours taken.
The HolidayRequestForm allows employees to make holiday requests. When a request is being made it effects the hourstaken column on the employees table.

I have a table in my web app that shows all holiday requests. I want all requests to appear here but I only ones that have been approved to be submitted to the employees table.

I have tried using if statements on my holiday request form.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "RequestID,EmployeeID,StartDate,FinishDate,HoursTaken,Comments,YearCreated,MonthCreated,DayCreated,YearOfHoliday,Approved")] HolidayRequestForm holidayRequestForm)
   {
  if (ModelState.IsValid && (holidayRequestForm.Approved == true))
  {
     db.HolidayRequestForms.Add(holidayRequestForm);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
   }

  else if (ModelState.IsValid && (holidayRequestForm.Approved == false))
  {
      db.HolidayRequestForms.Add(holidayRequestForm);
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  else if (ModelState.IsValid && (holidayRequestForm.Approved == null))
  {
      db.HolidayRequestForms.Add(holidayRequestForm);
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }

   ViewBag.EmployeeID = new SelectList(db.Employees, "EmployeeID", "FullName", holidayRequestForm.EmployeeID);
   return View(holidayRequestForm);
   }
```

I want it so that all records get shown on a the same table/view or perhaps different table/view so that a manager can approve/rejects holidays.

If approve, I want to save to the database.

Could I do this in sql server itself with a query in the business logic I used to show hourstaken in the employee table. I think that might be the best option but I'm unsure if I could handle it in asp.net mvc

Comment: Create ViewModel for common field of that two tables which you want to display in table. Also add IsApproved for approved/reject pass boolean value to your business logic and you get your result.

Comment: Okay, I understand!! Thanks